# Inserting Facebook Login button with innerHTML not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, button, authentication, innerhtml

I am trying to have my webpage react to if a user is signed in already via Facebook. When they ARE signed in, I want the place where the "Login with Facebook" button usually is to show a Settings/Logout button. If the use is not logged in, I want it to show the Facebook Login button.

The code I have to do this looks like this, where I use innerHTML to set what I want.

```
var login_area = document.getElementById("login-area");
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
  login_area.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" onclick="settings()"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-lg"></i></button><button id="login-button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" onclick="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>';
} else {
  // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
  login_area.innerHTML = '<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="user_friends" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>';
}
```

This code works exactly as intended in Firefox, but for Chrome, the Login button is not being displayed. It is there when I go to inspect element, but it displays nothing on the actual page.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Facebook SDK have no idea that you added a new tag in the document. You have to use FB.XFBML.parse ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ ) to tell the Facebook SDK about it.